# Rails nesting unrelated forms

Tags: ruby-on-rails, simple-form

I have one form nested within another. The inner form looks like this:

```
= simple_form_for @new_player, url: register_player_path, remote: true, do |pf|
    ...
    = pf.button :submit
```

However, when I click `submit` on the inner button, it tries to submit the outer form. How can I fix this? I want to keep both submit buttons.

Answer (score 0):

There are some good videos on Railscasts.com about nested forms. I'm sure you can get to a solution watching them :

http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-part-1

http://railscasts.com/episodes/197-nested-model-form-part-2

Comment: Love the casts. My issue is slightly different though. I have two separate forms that I'd like to keep separate; my inner form isn't related to the outer at all.